SQLPS works fine on PS4 but fails to load on PS7
this is just myself trying to get a reasonable explanation, i bypassed the problem.
On my server i have 2 versions of Powershell: 4.0 and 7.4
If i open up the two consoles and issue the command Get-Module -ListAvailable SQLPS shows up in both.
But if i try to issue a command like Invoke-Sqlcmd or Import-Module SQLPS it works on PS4 but fails on PS7:
Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Culture
=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'd understand (and use the usual "delete the folder and reinstall" method) if it has failed on both version. But it works fine on PS4, PS7 cannot find the file while PS4 can?
As i said, this is not a real problem, i managed to import my data in the DB via DTSX, but i just want to understand why.
Thanks for any help on the subject

Update the module on PS7 and try again.
